# Alterar e desabilitar campo após uma seleção

Tags: javascript

Acredito que ja tenha uma pergunta respondida mais ou menos com o que eu quero, mas não manjo muito de js e não consegui filtrar informações necessárias nas que eu li ... ENTÃO!

Gostaria de saber como poderia fazer para que assim que eu selecionasse a `<option value="Jurídica">` do meu `<select>`, o `<input id="name">` alterasse automaticamente seu `placeholder="* Nome Completo"` para `placeholder="*Nome de sua Empresa"` e que no `<input name="cpf">` fosse adicionado a propriedade `disabled` ou `readonly`.

```
<form>
    <select name="pessoa" id="pessoa">
        <option value="Não especificado">*Tipo de Pessoa</option>
        <option value="Física">Física</option>
        <option value="Jurídica">Jurídica</option>
    </select>

    <input name="nome" id="nome" placeholder="Nome Completo">
    <input name="icpf" id="icpf" placeholder="CPF">
    <input name="icnpj" id="icnpj" placeholder="CNPJ">
```

Segue form no JsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/LhanL/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode fazer assim: http://jsfiddle.net/z2jfx/

```
// select
var select = document.getElementById("pessoa");
// input
var input = document.getElementById("nome");

// quando o select muda
select.onchange = function () {
    var valor = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
    input.value = valor == 'Jurídica' ? '* Nome de sua Empresa' : '* Nome Completo';
}
```

Isto faz com que, quando o select muda, ele vai verificar se o valor escolhido é `'Jurídica'`. Se fôr o input muda para `'* Nome de sua Empresa'`, caso contrário `'* Nome Completo'`.

Note que estas funcionalidades podem/devem ser feitas por uma biblioteca como o MooTools ou jQuery que tomam em conta todas as maneiras diferentes como os Browsers (especialmente os antigos) reagem.

O código em cima é javascript puro e isso é semprre mais rápido (sem carregar biblioteca), testei agora no IE7 e IE8.

Para desabilitar os `input` pode usar assim dentro fa função `onchange`:

```
var habilitar = valor == 'Jurídica' ? true : false;
document.getElementById("icpf").disabled = habilitar;
document.getElementById("icnpj").disabled = !habilitar;
```

<sub>Porém começo a achar a solução demasiado personalizada.</sub>

Comment: Js é demais cara, estou estudando mas é tanta coisa que num da pra me concentrar em 1 ... @Sergio mas tem uma coisa, sem querer abusar, supondo que os campos `CPF`e `CNPJ` estejam `Disabled`como faço pra quando a pessoa escolher o tipo de pessoa `Física` habilitar o campo CPF e quando escolher `Jurídica` habilitar o campo `CNPJ`?

E sem querer abusar ja abusando, tem como deixar a mensagem "Selecione o tipo de pessoa" enquanto os campos estiverem desabilitados? Agradeço desde já!

Comment: @ViniciusColares, tinha esquecido a parte do `disabled`. Aqui vai. Entretanto começo a achar que você podia fazer de outra maneira. Podia esconder o campo em vez de estar disabled. Aí o utilizador nem percebe que o input muda. Ou melhor, use só um input e verifique com RegEx qual o numero introduzido... De qq maneira o jsFiddle: __http://jsfiddle.net/z2jfx/1/__

Comment: gostei da sua ideia, mas da forma que ficou está ótimo, só tenho uma dúvida, no caso desse js que vc fez, quando escolho o valor `Jurídica` ele adiciona a propriedade `value` com o respectivo valor ... tem como ao inves de adicionar `value`adicionar a propriedade `Placeholder`?

Comment: @ViniciusColares, sim claro, pode usar `input.placeholder = valor == 'Jurídica' ? '* Nome de sua Empresa' : '* Nome Completo';`.

Comment: Não entendo ... eu digitei EXATAMENTE isso e não funcionou, daí copie o q vc sugeriu e funcionou!
UHSAUHSAUHSAHUSAHUASHUAS

Comment: @ViniciusColares, boa! Se acha que a resposta resolve o seu problema pode marcar como aceite.

Comment: foi mal, ja tinha marcado como "aceito" mas tinha dado um bug srsrsrsrsrsrsrs

Cara mais uma coisa (Eu abuso né?) vc acha q tem como tipo assim, quando eu escolher entre pessoa física ou jurídica, teria como esconder a primeira opção?

Comment: @ViniciusColares, http://jsfiddle.net/z2jfx/2/

Comment: Valeu @Sergio você manja dos paranauê ... agr chega de abuso, só queria saber de vc se vc tem algum livro ou curso online que possa indicar, pra que eu possa aprender de maneira prática e rápida essas técnicas simples e puras em Js!

Comment: @ViniciusColares, este site é a melhor escola. Você quer fazer boas perguntas, aí estuda melhor o problema => Quando a resposta vem você está receptivo e compreende bem melhor a solução.

Comment: concordo mas me sinto abusivo, pq tipo ... dps que me mandou esse js tou há mais de meia hora tentando mudar ele pra deixar o form como tinha dito e não consigo, mas fico incomodado de ficar pedindo! XD

Comment: @ViniciusColares, se fôr um problema novo ou próximo passo da pergunta anterior, __e__ você não consegue resolver sozinho, então faça nova pergunta. Vai ter gente ajudando.

Comment: olha só, consegui fazer isso aqui ... http://jsfiddle.net/z2jfx/4/

Mas falta remover a opção `Selecione o tipo de pessoa` do select quando Física ou Jurídica estiver ativo, pode fazer isso pra mim?

Comment: @ViniciusColares :) http://jsfiddle.net/z2jfx/5/

Comment: =D isso é muito irado ficou perfeito ... valew!