# Como eu faço um input ser ativado depois que dois select sejam selecionados em javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Alguém pode me ajudar? Preciso fazer esse input do tipo submit só seja habilitado assim que os select á baixo forem selecionados, em javascript(sou iniciante)

```html
<select id="select1">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>

<select id="select2">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>

<input type="submit" id="submit" disabled>
```

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Alterar e desabilitar campo após uma seleção](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/20586/alterar-e-desabilitar-campo-ap%c3%b3s-uma-sele%c3%a7%c3%a3o)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom, acredito que criar dois EventListeners sobre as combo-boxes já deve resolver seu problema.

Basta criar os EventListeners, verificando o evento `change`, assim, sempre que o valor mudar, a verificação de ambos os campos será realizada.

Na função de verificação, ao retornar `verdadeiro`, basta atribuir `false` à propriedade `disabled` do input. E quando você selecionar novamente a combo-box com o texto vazio, a função atribuirá `true` para a propriedade `disabled` do input.

Algo do tipo:

```
    <select id="select1">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
    </select>

    <select id="select2">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
    </select>

    <input type="submit" id="submit" disabled>
```

```
<script>
    const select1 = document.getElementById('select1');
    const select2 = document.getElementById('select2');
    const input = document.getElementById('submit');

    function submit() {
        if (select1.value != '' && select2.value != '') {
            input.disabled = false;
        }
        else {
            input.disabled = true;
        }
    }

    select1.addEventListener('change', submit);
    select2.addEventListener('change', submit);
</script>
```